# Positioning a box at X and Y coords in CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's say that i have a 400px width x 400px height container div, i want to place inside this container a box. I have two X and Y coords which should determine the position of that box inside the container.

I don't really understand which CSS statement i should use to set the position according to those two parameters. From what i know i need 4 parameters to position a box inside another box: `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`, how can i do that with only two?

Comment: you dont need all four, only top/bottom and left/right is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of positioning one div inside another, you need `position: relative` on the outer div and `position: absolute` on the inner div.

then you can use top/bottom to control the y position, and left/right to control the x position of the inner div inside the outer div.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.top {
  top: 50px;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner top">using top property</div>
  <div class="inner bottom">using bottom property</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I now understand!

Comment: Just one thing: what would be the difference of using bottom instead of top in your code?

Comment: the difference is say if i use `top: 50px`, then the inner div is 50px down from the `top of parent div`, but if i use `bottom: 50px`, then the inner div is 50px up from `bottom of parent div`, the same applies for left/right. I hope this makes sense, i edited my answer to give you a visual idea.

Comment: Yes i understand!